# Computer graphics: Linear Interpolation

Tags: graphics

I have two vector points $p_1$ and $p_2$. Each point has a color value $c_1$ and $c_2$.
Now using *linear interpolation*, I would like to get the color value at point $p_3$.

Concrete example:

$\qquad \displaystyle p_1 = (1, 3) \text{ with } c_1 = (2, 4, 1)$
$\qquad \displaystyle p_2 = (4, 4) \text{ with } c_2 = (3, 1, 2)$

What color does $p_3 = (2,3)$ have?

Comment: Do you know what linear interpolation is in general? How have you tried to apply this here? (You were probably given a definition of linear interpolation in your context; if so, please share it with us.)

Comment: If this is a gamedev related question involving interpolation, you might get better answers at [gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Normally in graphics, you interpolate values across a line like so:
[image]

Point $A$ has value $V_A$ and point $B$ has value $V_B$, then you want to blend the value/color linearly between them as $C$ moves between $A$ and $B$. To do this, you first calculate the ratio (or percentage) of how far $C$ lies across the line $\overline {AB}$. This is equal to $\overline{AC}$ over $\overline {AB}$. Thus the ratio is calculated as follows:

$$
t=\frac {(C-A)}{(B-A)}
$$

Once you have this ratio, you can use it to find the interpolated value between $V_A$ and $V_B$, since they should have the same ratio.

$$
t=\frac {V_C - V_A}{V_B - V_A}
$$

The unknown variable here is $V_C$, so solving for $V_C$:

$$
(V_B - V_A)t=V_C-V_A\\
V_C=(V_B - V_A)t+V_A
$$

However, this assumes that point $C$ lies on the line $\overline {AB}$. If it is not on the line, then you can't really "interpolate" in this way without some additional definition of *what* you want to interpolate. For example, if $C$ lies far below the line, then you can't really compare $\overline {AC}$ to $\overline {AB}$ like this; the ratio can be greater than 1, even though $C$ is "in between" them. So in your example, point $(2,3)$ is off the line. You have many possible variants.

**For instance:**

- You can interpolate between the distances of $\overline {AC}$ and ${BC}$. You would thus create a new straight line, $\overline {ACB}$ (even though in the graph it would be an angle) and do the above interpolation on that.
- You can interpolate a particular color to a dimension. For example, you take the values $A_x$, $B_x$ and $C_x$, and interpolate $\overline {A_xC_x}$ over $\overline {A_xC_xB_x}$, and use that for Red, then use $y$ for Green etc. However this works better for 3 dimensions, where each dimension can correlate to a color.

Comment: You could also interpolate along a parallel of $\overline{AB}$, which would yield what graphic programs call "linear" gradient (as opposed to "radial"). (Come to think of it, your answer could be improved by posting example pictures!)

Comment: I was going to add this with a slightly different wording: to project $C$ to $\overline{AB}$ and interpolate the projected point as before. I think this is the same as what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but here is an idea.

First you have to express $p_3$ as a linear combination of $p_1$ and $p_2$. This can be done by solving a linear system say

$$
\lambda p_1 +\mu p_2 =p_3.
$$

In your case you want to solve
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda + 4\mu &= 2 \\
3\lambda + 4\mu &= 3
\end{align}.
$$

Then you use the parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ to compute $c_3$ by
$$c_3=\lambda c_1 +\mu c_2.$$